# When should non-resident alien investors file IRS taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, starting-out-investing

I am a [*non-resident alien*](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-persons) with a tax residency in my country of origin. I have opened an investment account with a broker in the United States.

What (if at all) do I have to file with the IRS?

Comment: For most common investments, nothing. Dividends are taxed at release, you don't have to file anything.